# ::before and ::after doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get these two objects fixed on the users screen. Please note that I can only modify this with using CSS so the **HTML can't be edited**!, this is a [CSS zen garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) example (based on the '90s) I'm trying (which means in short you make a design based on a fixed html file so you can 'show off' what CSS is capable off.)

[image]

You can find a live example here.
http://lucasdebelder.be/zengarden/index.html

I got the top **fixed and working** with the following syntax.

```
body::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12.5%;
    background: url(header_browser.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: 5000;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

I then tried the ::after statement on the body. But that doesn't work how can I get the bottom image (footer) sticked to the bottom?

```
body::after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12.5%;
    background: url(footer_browser.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: 5000;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tell your `::before` pseudo element to go up the top at `0`.
Tell your `::after` pseudo element to go down the bottom at `0`.

```css
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.5%;
  background: #0f0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-size: 100%;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.5%;
  background: #f00;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You should also include `top: 0;` in the `::before` to make sure it always lives at the exact top of the screen.

Comment: @Zze Thanks a lot for the answer I have applied the syntax. But I have one last problem, if I scale my window down or up the bottom bar keeps changing position, how can I get around that? I have updated the website. http://lucasdebelder.be/zengarden/index.html

Comment: @Intervalia The bottom bar keeps going up and down now on rescale, do you know how to get around that? I have updated the site with the code above. http://lucasdebelder.be/zengarden/index.html

Comment: Do you mean that they move a little and then go back to their correct place? That is common. Not sure why the browser manufacturers don't fix that, but it does bounce a little and then ends up in the correct place. If that is not what you are talking about, let me know. And make sure you are using `position: fixed;`

Comment: @Panic - See above, comment, also if that is not what you are referring to, please update your question.